# Repeated lines/stripes using for loops in Java

Tags: java, loops

i want to paint black and white stripes on the image, switching every 20th column both horizontally and vertically on top of an image while staying inside it's borders. so far i can get a black square with 1 pixel wide vertical stripes. i've tried to at least get skinny white stripes on my horizontal lines by switching things around but it's still vertical.

```
public void zebraStripes() {

    Image img = ImageViewer.getImage();

    double numPixelsWide = img.getWidth();
    int numPixelsHigh = img.getHeight();


    Color c = Color.WHITE;
    Color b = Color.BLACK;


    double i = numPixelsWide;
    if (i % 20 == 0) {

        for (int x = 0; x < numPixelsHigh; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < i; y++) {
                img.setPixelColor(y, x, b);
                }

            for (int z = 19; z < i; z = z + 20) {
                    img.setPixelColor(z, x, c);
            }
        }
    }
}

// paint black and white stripes (left to right) on the image, switching
// every 20th row
public void jailBird() {

    Image img = ImageViewer.getImage();

    double numPixelsWide = img.getWidth();
    double numPixelsHigh = img.getHeight();

    Color c = Color.WHITE;
    Color b = Color.BLACK;

    double i = numPixelsHigh;
    if (i % 20 == 0) {

        for (int x = 0; x < numPixelsHigh; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < i; y++) {
                img.setPixelColor(y, x, b);
                }

            for (int z = 19; z < i; z = z + 20) {
                    img.setPixelColor(z, x, c);
            }
                }
            }
        }

}
```

how do i get the white stripes to be 20 pixels wide and horizontal?

Comment: For better help sooner consider posting an [MCVE]. The C stands for Complete - it should include all needed to compile and run.

Comment: Don’t use `==` on doubles. Part of your problem may be an error where `numPixlesHigh` is divisible by 20 alright, but due to precision problems with doubles `i % 20` doesn’t yield exacly 0.0. Unlikely, but better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested! Hope it gets you going.

```
    // paint a 20 pixels wide horizontal line for every 40 pixels
    for (int y = 0; y < numPixelsHigh; y += 40) {
        // paint a stripe
        for (int ys = y; ys < y + 20; ys++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < numPixelsWide; x++) {
                img.setPixelColor(x, ys, Color.BLACK);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It may try to paint outside the image, since `ys` can go up to `numPixelsHisgh + 18`. I’m sure you’ll be able to repair this yourself if it’s a problem.